# C++ function to create and destroy temporary with given type and constructor parameters

Tags: c++, raii, visitor-pattern, variadic

I'm finding a lot of the following in my code:

```
{
    SomeClass<VisitorType> obj(visitor, param1, param2, 3, 4);
}
{
    OtherClass<VisitorType> obj(visitor, 5, "six");
}
```

The braces are necessary to ensure that the object's lifetime is constrained work is done in constructor and destructor (RAII style).  There is good reason for this and other users of these class templates do more than just construct and destruct.

Is there a convenient idiom to boil this down to something like a function call, where possible retaining strong typing?

e.g.

```
f<SomeClass>(visitor, param1, param2, 3, 4);
f<OtherClass>(visitor, 5, "six");
```

where `f<>()` is something like:

```
template <template <class> class C, class V>
void f(V &v, ...)
{
    C<V> c(v, ...); // magic needed here
}
```

I tried using variadic functions but hit a load of compilation errors.  I would prefer not to use macros if possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
SomeClass<VisitorType>(visitor, param1, param2, 3, 4);
```

This seems to work for me.

However, I wouldn't leave such a line of code in some function without providing a comment explaining that leaving out the object was intentional. A function, on the other hand, would be a convenient place to put such documentation:

```
// call C<V>'s ctor, leaving the caller to decide when to call dtor
template<template <class> class C, typename V, typename... Args>
C<V> fire_and_forget(V& visitor, Args&&... args) {
  return C<V>(visitor, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Then use it thus:

```
fire_and_forget<SomeClass>(visitor, param1, param2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: The problem is the scope of that temporary - it isn't destructed right away so still needs to be wrapped in braces.

Comment: @paperjam: The temporary must be destructed at the end of the full expression, which is at the `;`. If your compiler fails to do that, then that would indeed be a bad bug.

Comment: Note that you could also wrap this in a function and return a temporary, which would aswell be destroyed at the `;`.

Comment: @Xeo: I was thinking about this, but then thought "why?" Now rethinking this, I might lean towards it for documentation. Thanks for bringing it up again, I'll put it into the answer.

Comment: I think paperjam needs to do stuff before the object is destroyed, although I guess he could wrap it in methods and call using the temporary.

Comment: @Pubby: Mhmm. I didn't read his question in this way. ("...other users of these class templates do more than just construct and destruct.")

Comment: @sbi: I actually meant that as a way to deduce the template type for `SomeClass` (`VisitorType`). `make_someclass(visitor, ...)`.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, of course, if this works out in the OP's case. We know too little, though — not even whether `VisitorType` and `visitor` correspond.

Comment: @sbi: We do know enough, see the `f` template example at the end. :)

Comment: @Xeo: Ah, indeed. _Sigh._ I changed my answer. This is slowly getting to the point where I really need to run it through a compiler to be sure it actually even compiles. Please bear with me if I failed.

Comment: @sbi - you're right, the scope ends with the `;`.  Thanks all.

Comment: You forgot the rvalue references.

Comment: And the calls to `std::forward` then.

Comment: @DeadMG & Xeo: I give up. I'm not even working with C++ anymore, let alone C++11. I'll make this CW, please you guys go in and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (C++11):

```
template<typename class_t, typename... args_t>
void cdtor(args_t... args) {
  class_t(args...) obj;
  // do stuff with obj
} 

cdtor<foo>(1, 2, 3);
```

Although macros would work just as well:

```
#define cdtor(x) do { auto obj = x; /* do stuff with obj */ } while(false)

cdtor(foo(1, 2, 3));
```

C++03 macro with `typeof` extension:

```
#define cdtor(x) do { typeof(x) obj = x; /* do stuff with obj */ } while(false)
```

Comment: @paperjam Yes. The macro uses less c++11 features - you can use typeof instead of auto.

Comment: @paperjam: This is variadic templates of C++11.